# React-Chartjs-2 How to create dashed gridlines

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Im using react-chartjs-2 and trying to create dashed gridlines on the y-axis

I tried to look on Chart Config Web: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration

But cant find the trick

Here is my code:

```
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import {Chart as ChartJS, registerables} from 'chart.js';
ChartJS.register(...registerables);

const data = {
    labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'legend1',
        data: [12, 19, 3],
    },{
        label: 'legend2',
        data: [22, 9, 13],
      
    }]
};

const options = {
    scales: {
        y: {
            grid: {
                tickBorderDash: [4, 4],
                tickColor: '#000',
                tickWidth: 2,
                offset: true,
                drawTicks: true,
                drawOnChartArea: true
            },

            beginAtZero: true,
        },
        x: {
            display: false
        }
    },
};


const BarChart = (props : Props) => {
    return (
        
        <Chart type='bar' data={data} options={options} />

    );
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking at the source code, I gathered that for some reason `y.grid.tickBorderDash` option only applies to the tick marks, not for the grid lines. Actually, the option is applied only for lines that are not affected by `drawOnChartArea: true`.

To make y axis gridlines dashed, one has to set `y.border.dash` option. This doesn't seem very consistent to me, but that's the way the code currently functions.

So this should work:

```js
const options = {
    scales: {
        y: {
            border:{dash: [4, 4]}, // for the grid lines
            grid: {
                color: '#aaa', // for the grid lines
                tickColor: '#000', // for the tick mark
                tickBorderDash: [2, 3], // also for the tick, if long enough
                tickLength: 10, // just to see the dotted line
                tickWidth: 2,
                offset: true,
                drawTicks: true, // true is default 
                drawOnChartArea: true // true is default 
            },

            beginAtZero: true,
        },
        x: {
            display: false
        }
    },
};
```

**Note**: I tested with `charts.js` 4.2.0 (latest at the time of posting).